when calculating expected value of a n - random sample we divide by n?
It may be a stupid question, but i can't help myself understanding why if we have a random variable X, which has a certain distribution, and we pick n i.i.d random variables to create a random sample of size n, we have to divide by n the sum to get the expected value.
I thought it would make more sense to weight each value in the random sample with the probability of being drawn instead of 1/sample size. Does it depend on how a random sample is defined?
thanks everyone

"I thought it would make more sense to weight each value in the random sample with the probability of being drawn instead of 1/sample size." How would you determine this probability? Suppose you are drawing numbered balls from an urn and you can't see inside. How would you know the probability of a ball being labeled, say, three?

If you want to estimate the average height of an adult, would you seriously sum the heights of $100$ adults and then divide by $7$ billion?  That would make the average height $0$, effectively.

It sounds like you know the distribution already, when you are talking about weighing values with the probability of being drawn. Of course this will get you closer to the actual mean, but then, why not just take the actual mean, if you know it already?

I think you are mixing different concepts... Every variable $X_i$ has the same expected value, as they are i.d. (identically distributed), say $E[X_i] = \mu$. The point is that the value of $\mu$ is generally unknown. If you draw a sample of size $n$, you can compute
$$
E\left[\frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]= \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i] = \frac 1n \sum_{i=1}^n \mu = \mu.
$$
Hence, the expected value of the average of the $X_i$ is also $\mu$. With this in mind, you can use the sample mean as an estimate for the true expected value, $\mu$.

If you know the distribution, you don't take a random sample of it. You simply take each possible output, weight it by its probability, and add up the sum.
Taking a random sample to estimate the mean is something you do when you don't know enough about the distribution to assign a probability to each value you observe.
But suppose you know the distribution and decide to take a random sample anyway. Consider a Bernoulli distribution with parameter $\frac23$; that is, $\frac23$ probability of outcome $1$, $\frac13$ probability of outcome $0$.
Suppose you take a sample of three observations from this distribution. If we don't care about which order the results come in (because addition is commutative), the most likely outcome is some permutation of $1$ two times and $0$ once.
Add these up according to your scheme:
\begin{align}
1 \times \frac23 &= \frac23, \\
1 \times \frac23 &= \frac23, \\
0 \times \frac13 &= 0, \\
\text{total} &= \frac43.
\end{align}
So you get the result $\frac43$, which is greater than the maximum possible outcome.
Contrast this with the calculation
\begin{align}
1 \times \frac23 &= \frac23, \\
0 \times \frac13 &= 0, \\
\text{total} &= \frac23.
\end{align}
This is a correct calculation of the mean where you count each possible outcome exactly once, regardless of how many times it might occur in any random sample.
So yes, the difference is all about how a random sample is defined. A good random sample will observe each outcome many times, and the number of times the outcome is observed will tend to reflect the probability of that outcome.
For example, if you take a random sample of $100$ observations from the Bernoulli distribution with $p=\frac23$, you might get the outcome $1$ sixty-five times, in which case your estimated mean is $1 \times \frac{65}{100} = 0.65$, or you might get the outcome $1$ seventy times, in which case your estimated mean is $1 \times \frac{70}{100} = 0.7$, or you might get some other result, but most likely you will get something near the actual mean, which is $\frac23$.
The key notion is that the number of times you observe a certain outcome -- for example $70$ -- divided by the number of times you sampled the distribution -- for example $100$ -- is the best way we have to estimate the probability of each outcome.
So the reason we divide by the sample size is essentially because we do want to weight each possible value by its probability, but the sample tends to contain multiple occurrences of each value, and when we count them up and divide by the sample size it approximates the probability of that particular value as an outcome.
